# Java Selenium cucumber error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have made simple cucumber class and trying to learn.

I am trying to run cucumber class, but I keep getting this error.

What do I need to fix something?

Any help would be appreciated.

I am facing this error.

I added a picture.
[image: I added pic.]

[image]
Class

```
package StepDefinitions;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/Features", glue= {"StepDefinitions"})
public class running {

    public running() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

This error occurs when I run the program.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3215)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3420)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2165)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:513)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.runtime.TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 18 more
```

New update after I added io cucumber core.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/messages/Messages$Envelope
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.NoPublishFormatter.setEventPublisher(NoPublishFormatter.java:34)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.Plugins.setEventBusOnEventListenerPlugins(Plugins.java:71)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:228)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.messages.Messages$Envelope
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 11 more
```

depdencies here

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you try to add cucumber-core
also use same versions for all cucumber packages.

actually try directly to upgrade cucumber-junit to 7

Comment: I upgraded cucumber junit and junit to 7.0.0 and 4.13.2, but still getting same error.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier

Comment: I reproduced the issue and when I upgraded cucumber-junit to 7.0.0 it worked. Don't forget to reload maven dependencies

Comment: Hmm. This should work if you had the same issue and reproduced, but I am still getting the same error after I reloaded the maven dependencies.

Comment: you can also try to add cucumber-core:6.11.0 into your pom.xml
This way I could run as well. I believe at major upgrade to 7.0.0 they added some core libraries into cucumber-junit.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited my post to add dependencies, and picture. Could you please look into it? still not working.

Comment: please include this one https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core/6.11.0

info.cukes is moved to io.cucumber

Comment: @memoricab Thank you for continuing to help me. I did that into my pom and got more errors. Instead of, I did latest io.cucumber core and got 11 more than 18 more errors in the picture above. Some errors were decreased. Wow I don't know what problem is casuing. I added new errors in the body.

Comment: Oh. It somehow worked from your link. Finally everything works! Thank you so much!!! @memoricab

Comment: I will update my answer, could you please mark it as a valid answer?

Comment: Yes I marked your answer plus up! Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue.

Please upgrade your cucumber-junit to 7.0.0

or you can use io.core:cucumber-core:6.11.0 with your 6.11.0 cucumber-junit dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that cucumber-core, cucumber-java and cucumber-testng have same version.for example

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
```