# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier exception

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-junit

I am working on serenity BDD with maven, java and Junit. I have setup a framework with maven and When i run project using `mvn clean verify` i keep getting the below issue. can someone help me with this?

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>BDD project </artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>BDD project using Cucumber</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-ensure</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0 </version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>

        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber6</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-configuration/commons-configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-reports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-reports</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.applitools/eyes-selenium-java3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.applitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>eyes-selenium-java3</artifactId>
            <version>3.208.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ozlerhakan/poiji -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ozlerhakan</groupId>
            <artifactId>poiji</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.aerogear/aerogear-otp-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.aerogear</groupId>
            <artifactId>aerogear-otp-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>TestRunner.Mobile.mavenRunnerFile.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tags></tags>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error log:

```
[INFO] Running TestRunner.Mobile.mavenRunnerFile
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.018 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestRunner.Mobile.mavenRunnerFile
[ERROR] TestRunner.Mobile.mavenRunnerFile  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.runtime.TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   mavenRunnerFile » NoClassDefFound io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigu...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- serenity-maven-plugin:3.2.0:aggregate (serenity-reports) @ SerenityIntellij ---
[INFO] Test results for 0 tests generated in 644 ms in directory: file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/SerenityIntellij/target/site/serenity/
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:verify (default)
```

Runner file:

```
package TestRunner.Mobile;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        features = "src/test/java/features/Account/ACCT-1339 Ability to resend confrim msg/"
)
public class mavenRunnerFile {
}
```

I'm kind of stuck with this issue. Please let me know how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you comment out `cucumber-junit` dependency? Please also check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69824742/java-selenium-cucumber-errorjava-lang-noclassdeffounderror-io-cucumber-core-ru helps

Comment: @samabcde yes I followed the answers from the above link however i end up with the same issue. 'cucumber-junit' did not solve the problem so I comment out.

Comment: You should not use `serenity-cucumber6` as your cucumber version is 7. Try using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber/3.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is [`serenity-cucumber6`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber6) which is for integration with cucumber 6 is not compatible with cucumber 7. `serenity-cucmber` with version > [3.1.13](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber/3.1.13) should be used to work with cucumber 7.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber6</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```