# Java Selenium Cucumber error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: "io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier"

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, serenity

I have made simple cucumber class and trying to learn.

I am trying to run cucumber class, but I keep getting this error.

What do I need to fix something?

I am facing this error.

I updated added io.cucumber but I am still getting the same error.

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
glue = {"ho.qat.seo.stepDefinitions"},
plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
tags = ""
)
public class TestRunner {
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ho.qat.heo</groupId>
<artifactId>seo-technical-task</artifactId>

<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>SEO Technical Task</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <serenity.version>2.3.8</serenity.version>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>2.3.6</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.plugin.version>3.0.0-M4</maven.plugin.version>
    <parallel.tests>4</parallel.tests>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.44</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.44</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.44</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber6</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.24.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.thucydides</groupId>
        <artifactId>thucydides-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.275</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Run parallel tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <forkCount>${parallel.tests}</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <includes>**/TestRunner*.java</includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`error:`

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier`

```
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.runtime.TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Selenium cucumber error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/runtime/TypeRegistryConfigurerSupplier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69824742/java-selenium-cucumber-errorjava-lang-noclassdeffounderror-io-cucumber-core-ru)

Comment: When posting code here, paste the code in, select it with your mouse, and click the code formatting tool in the editor. You don't need to add backticks in manually - that can often cause a mess anyway.